# How do you increase your performance through circut training?

Tags: circuit-training

My aim is to improve the rep numbers of burpees, lunges, push ups and some other exercises that I do. I opt for circuit training alone. However, I dont have much experience in circuit training.

What efficient ways are there to progress to higher volume with circuit training. I know that there are ways of increasing another round and minimizing the rest times. But what methods work the best with circuit training?

Comment: How long have you been doing circuits? If you're just starting then isn't the answer simply that you'll get better at it by doing it for a few months?

Comment: Lets say I did circuit training for a year, and reached plateaus. What ways are there to break plateaus.